# $X\stackrel d= Y$. What does it exactly mean?

Tags: probability

When we write $X\stackrel d= Y$, does this mean that $X$ and $Y$ have exactly the same distribution?

For example, $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^{2}) \ \text{and}\ X\stackrel d= Y\implies Y\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ with the same values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

From what I understand in this  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) article, $X\stackrel d= Y\implies F_X(t)=F_Y(t)$ for all $t$, which would seem to imply the answer to my question is yes. But then it goes on to say that equality of distribution is the weakest form of equality/convergence usually discussed. What about this type of equality makes it *weak*?

Comment: $\stackrel{d}{=}$ means [equality in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$X\overset{d}{=}Y$ does mean equality in distribution, which implies that the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ agree, that is,
$$
F_X(t)=F_Y(t),\quad\forall t\in\Bbb R.
$$
Note that equality in distribution also sometimes goes by the name *equality in law*.

Since the notation $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is just a statement about the distribution of $X$, you can rightfully conclude
$$
X\overset{d}{=}Y\,\land\, X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)\implies Y\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2).
$$

In regards to the strength (or weakness) of such an equality, note that there are [multiple ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) we can describe the "equalness" of two random variables. The reason why equality in distribution is considered weak is because it does not imply actual observed values of $X$ and $Y$ will be similar or close in value.

For example, suppose $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(-1/2,1/2)$ and $Y=-X$. Then by change of variables (or just upon inspection) we can see that $Y\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(-1/2,1/2)$ and thus $X\overset{d}{=}Y$. But if you were to then draw observations from these distributions they would never by similar as they would always be opposite in sign.